# AngluarJS directive alternative of jsp tag library?

Tags: java, angularjs, jsp, taglib

I have recently gone through Angular js tutorials. Directives are one of the pillar of AngularJS.
My understnading is directives can be good substitue of custom JSP tag libraies (which developers develop
specific to each project). Is that correct ?

The  reason i am saying this JSP taglib are developed to have reusable ui component which can achieved by angularJs
directive that too on client side .

Comment: I upvoted because I like the idea :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are absolutely correct. Angular js directives play the same role as Tag libraries in JSP. The only difference in JSP tags generated code on the server side and sent it to client whereas angular directives generate code on the client side